# Setting HTML textarea contents with python, BeautifulSoup, mechanize (no forms, just divs)

Tags: python, forms, textarea, beautifulsoup, mechanize

I'm trying to fill out a form containing a textarea element.  I'm using Python with the BeautifulSoap and mechanize modules (stuck on 2.6.5 on FreeBSD 8.1 with the latest modules in the FreeBSD repository: BeautifulSoup 3.1.0.1 and mechanize 0.2.1).

The problem with BeautifulSoap is it doesn't properly set textarea contents (I can try `soup.textarea.insert(0, "FOO")` or even `soup.textarea.contents = "FOO"`, but once I check the current value with `soup.textarea`, I still see the old HTML  tags with no content between them:

`<textarea name="classified_description" class="classified_textarea_text"></textarea>`

The problem with mechanize is it only seems to operate on true forms.  Per the HTML I'm parsing below, this is not really a form, but rather a set of divs with input items inside.

How can I use Python or either of these modules to set the value of this textarea element?

```
<div class="classified_field">
            <div class="classified_input_label">Description</div>
            <div class="classified_textarea_div">
                <textarea name="classified_description" id="classified_description" class="classified_textarea_text"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="site_clear"></div>
        </div>
```

I'd tried Vladimir's technique below, and while it works with his example, it does not work in my production code for some reason.  I'm able to use `.find()` to get the `textarea`, but the `.insert()` is giving me grief.  Here's what I have so far:

```
>>> soup.find('textarea', {'name': 'classified_description'})                  
<textarea name="classified_description" class="classified_textarea_text"></textarea>
>>> soup.find('textarea', {'name': 'classified_description'}).insert(0, "some text here")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/BeautifulSoup.py", line 233, in insert
  newChild.nextSibling.previousSibling = newChild
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'previousSibling'
>>>
```

Anyone know why this would through the unicode error?  Clearly my `soup` object is not just a unicode string because I successfully use `.find`.

SOLUTION:
Vladimir's solution is correct, but it's possible for real-world HTML to generate a `malformed start tag` error in BeautifulSoup 3.1 ([official reason here](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/3.1-problems.html)).  After downgrading to BeautifulSoup 3.0.8, everything worked fine.  When I posted the initial question, I had to do some jury rigging to get mechanize to `read()` into the BeautifulSoup object so as not to geht the `malformed start tag` error.  This caused a uencode sting to be created instead of a BeautifulSoup object.  Correcting my mechanize code with the older BeautifulSoup has caused the desired behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example using BeautifulSoup:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup('<textarea name="classified_description"></textarea>')
soup.find('textarea', {'name': 'classified_description'}).insert(0, 'value')
assert str(soup) == '<textarea name="classified_description">value</textarea>'
```

[BeautifulSoup documentation on modifying the parse tree](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#Modifying%20the%20Parse%20Tree) describes such transformations in details.

Comment: Thanks! Your example works for me, but the production code throws an error: `AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'previousSibling'`.  Any clue why?

Comment: Somewhere in the code some function returns `unicode` while you expecting it to return soup tag object. Try to debug it yourself (for example introduce some variables http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/introduceExplainingVariable.html ). Btw, it's better when you accepts answer too ;)

Comment: I hope I wasn't rude by not marking your reply as an answer right away.  The problem persisted so I was waiting until complete resolution.  I now understand a bug in BeautifulSoup 3.1 (see my post edit).  Your answer is the correct solution for better builds of BeautifulSoup

Comment: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'previous_sibling'